# Getting realtime data from sub-collection in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page where there is Carousel, and inside the Carousel, there is a Gridview ( for every page of the Carousel we have one)!

Trying to display a list of photos inside Gridview , Everyday has new list of photo.

Not sure about the code bug here, follow up with the Firestore doc to get the data. Really appreciate the help and explanation on this matter.

> error : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty:
> 0

```
class SugarPhotoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SugarPhotoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SugarPhotoPage> createState() => _SugarPhotoPageState();
}

class _SugarPhotoPageState extends State<SugarPhotoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final dbRefPhotos = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('photos');
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = dbRefPhotos
        .doc(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()))
        .collection(DateFormat('KK:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now()))
        .snapshots();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _photoStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            return carsousel(snapshot, width, height);
          }),
    );
  }

  CarouselSlider carsousel(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> snapshot,
      double width, double height) {
    return CarouselSlider.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index, realIndex) {
        var data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

        return Stack(
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            topContainer(width),
          ],
        );
      }),
      options: CarouselOptions(
          viewportFraction: 1.0, enlargeCenterPage: false, height: height),
    );
  }

  Container topContainer(double width) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: 60,
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.7),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Date:\n${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now())}',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
          ),
          const Text(
            'Calories:',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Firestore screenshot
[image]

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you are checking `snapshot` in `_SugarPhotoPageState` if there is `error` or `connectionState` but you are not checking `hasData` witch check if you have data from you request to the database so you have tow solution :

**Solution 1:**
when the function `carsousel` get called it will expect `null` value in the `snapshot` so we add null safety to your code.

```
CarouselSlider carsousel(
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>? snapshot,
    double width,
    double height,
) {
    return CarouselSlider.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot?.data?.docs?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: ((context, index, realIndex) {
        var data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          ),
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        topContainer(width),
      ],
    );
  }),
  options: CarouselOptions(
      viewportFraction: 1.0, enlargeCenterPage: false, height: height),
 );
}
```

**Solution 2:**
you add `hasData` so before calling function `carsousel` you confirm that you received responses from the database.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _photoStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        } 
        if (snapshot.hasData){
            return carsousel(snapshot, width, height);
        }
        return const Text("Loading");
      }),
);
```

Comment: Hi, Ilyes. Really appreciate for taking the time to reply, Tried the solution, didn't work. Correct I forgot to set HasData method!.  
Wondering if this is because of architecture of  DataBase Design